# Получение данных из MySQL, jdbc, Android Studio

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc

Здравствуйте мне нужно получить список точек из бд. Я написал код по гайдам, всё компилируется, но список остаётся пустым (таблица заполнена).

```
public class MySQLHelper implements Runnable{

    private static final String URL = "url";
    private static final String USER = "name";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "password";

    public static ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String sql = "SELECT latitude, longitude FROM Placemarks";

        try(Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD)) {            Class.forName("com.st17.culturemap.jdbc.Driver").getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

            while(resultSet.next())
            {
                points.add(new Point(resultSet.getDouble("latitude"),resultSet.getDouble("longitude")));
            }

            resultSet.close();
            statement.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("InfoAsyncTask", "Error reading school information", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Так же если я добавляю точку при помощи кода, она всё равно не отображается

```
...
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Placemarks";
        points.add(new Point(57.841865, 60.594100));
        try(Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD)) {
            points.add(new Point(56.841865, 61.594100));
            Class.forName("com.st17.culturemap.jdbc.Driver").getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
...
```

Comment: Ссылку на гайд можно увидеть?

Answer (score 0):

Похоже гайд вы использовали вот этот
https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-read-mysql-data-from-android-using-jdbc/

Но в нем нет ничего подобного типа вашего

```
Class.forName("com.st17.culturemap.jdbc.Driver").getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
```

Возможно именно этот код крашит `try-catch` и после него ничего не выполняется.

Comment: После удаления, ничего не меняется

Так же я заметил, что если убрать
`implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.29'`
то программа не выдаёт ошибку

Comment: Какую ошибку, поделитесь.

Comment: Например если я убираю `implementation 'com.yandex.android:maps.mobile:4.0.0-full'` при компиляции получается ошибка

package com.yandex.mapkit does not exist
import com.yandex.mapkit.MapKit;

но при удалении `implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.29'` никакой ошибки не выходит.